# PERSISTENCE_DATAACCESS_EXCEPTION when trying to delete entity

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my book.java

it has

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private BookPeriodEnd period;
```

I want to delete a book object.

After it,

```
  bookRepository.delete(book);
```

It deletes but gives error and does not delete from `bookperiodend`:

> org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch
>   update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row
>   count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected
>   row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

also this

> INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR(PERSISTENCE_DATAACCESS_EXCEPTION) -
>   ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException : Batch update returned
>   unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected:
>   1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update
>   returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0;
>   expected: 1 (Batch update returned unexpected row count from update
>   [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1)
>   org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch
>   update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row
>   count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected
>   row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

before error, it outputs those queries:

```
Hibernate: delete from book where id=? and version=?
Hibernate: delete from book_period_end where id=? and version=?
```

but in the end it only deletes book.

Why is that?

Comment: Does that book id actually exist in book_period_end , beacuse Hibernate throw this kind if exception when it does not find the record in the database which it has to update

Comment: @IshantGaurav i can confirm for this query ```Hibernate: delete from book where id=? and version=?```, because i know id from query i am sending and version but for ```Hibernate: delete from book_period_end where id=? and version=?``` , i dont know the id. Book has period and so period_id in on it and that period exists on period table. But version confuses me

Comment: Can you please show your complete entity class ?

Comment: I removed  `(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` part so now only `@ManyToOne(
private BookPeriodEnd period;`
it seems working now. No need to cascade

Comment: But i have problem in modify - put. I changed to `  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`  but it gives `aused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing` error.

Comment: Without cascade type it should not work on child table. You should include  cascade=CascadeType.ALL  on your collection mapping.

This happens because you have a collection in your entity, and that collection has one or more items which are not present in the database. By specifying the above options you tell hibernate to save them to the database when saving their parent.